# Determine SQLite DATATYPE from Python class dinamically to create COLUMN

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

Using Python, I need to dynamically add columns to a table resident in a SQLite database.

I have a list of dicts formed this way:

```
records = [
    {'key1': 10,
     'key2': 'Foo text',
     'key3': datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 25, 12, 45, 20, 960723)
     'key4': 5.6
    },
    {'key2': 'Foo text',
     'key3': datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 25, 12, 45, 20, 960723)
     'key4': 5.6
     'key5': 'Apple'
    },
    {'key1': 10,
     'key4': 5.6
     'key8': datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 25, 12, 45, 20, 960723)
     'key9': None
    }
]
```

Let's also say that all the values stored in the dicts are simple objects (dates, strings, floats, integers)

I have a table resident in a SQLite db defined this way:

```
CREATE TABLE foo_table (
    row_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    key1 INTEGER NOT NULL
)
```

After retrieving from the table all the column names already inserted (which I can do using `PRAGMA table_info(fe_parser)` and iterating over the results), let's say I have a list `columns_in_db` that contains all the columns name that are already defined in `foo_table`.

Iterating over `records` I can easily find the keys that are not defined in `foo_table`:

```
for el in records:
    for k in el:
         if k, value not in columns_in_db.items():
--->         # CODE_TO_ADD 
             columns_in_db.append(k)
```

Where CODE_TO_ADD would be something similar to:

```
cursor.execute(f"ALTER TABLE foo_table ADD {k} {type_to_str(value)};")
```

Is there any easy way to match python objects with the SQL column definition? Otherwise, do you have any suggestion on how to write the `type_to_str` function?

Thanks in advance. 
Giacomo

Comment: You could just leave off the type. It's not required in sqlite tables.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful, I didn't know. Anyway, wanting to explicit datatype, I've created a very simple function that receives `obj.__class__.__name__` as a parameter, parses looking for some datatype and returns the SQLite definition of the datatype.